# Lottery program (Ascending order, non-repeating etc)

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble making a lottery progam. I recently got into programming so I dont understand too much about it.
So the person is supposed to be able and choose how many rows of number he wants. Then 7 random numbers between 1-35 should appear, in ascending order and non-repeating in that row (it can appear again in the next row).
I'm using rand / srand to make "random" numbers.

Any help would be nice! 
Thanks in advance! :)

This is what the code looks like atm.

```
void randNr(int[]);
int main()
{
    int rad;
    string svar, igen;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");


    cout << "Hur många rader vill du ha? Välj ett tal mellan 1-12." << endl;            //How many rows do you want?
    cin >> rad;
    for (int a = 1; a < 7; a++)
    {
        if (rad < 0 || rad > 12)
        {
            if (cin.fail())
            {
                system("CLS");
                cin.clear();
            }
            cout << "Fel inmatning, Välj ett av alternativen. \n" << endl;          //Wrong answer, choose one of the alternatives
            cout << "För att börja om tryck 'j'." << endl;                          //'j' to start over
            cout << "För att avsluta tryck 'n'." << endl;                           //'n' to quit program
            cin >> svar;

            if (svar == "j" || svar == "J" || svar == "Ja" || svar == "ja")
            {
                system("CLS");
                return main();
            }
            else if (svar == "n" || svar == "N" || svar == "Nej" || svar == "nej")
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if (svar != "j" && svar != "J" && svar != "Ja" || svar != "n" && svar != "N" && svar != "nej" && svar != "Nej")
            {
                system("CLS");
            }

        }
    }
    randNr(tal);

while (true) {

        cout << "\nFör att köra igen: tryck 'j'" << endl;           //To play again press 'j'
        cout << "För att avsluta  : tryck 'n'" << endl;             // To quit, press 'n'
        cin >> igen;
        if (igen == "j" || igen == "J" || igen =="Ja" || igen == "ja")                          
        {
            system("CLS");
            return main();
        }
            else if(igen == "n" || igen == "N" || igen == "nej" || igen == "Nej" )
            {
                system("CLS");
                return 0;
            }
                else
                {
                    system("CLS");
                    cout << "Fel inmatning, välj ett av alternativen" << endl;  //Wrong answer, choose on of the alternatives
                }           
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void randNr(int tal[])
{
    //DONT KNOW HOW TO DO THE ASCENDING / NON REPEATING PART 
    //---------------------HERE---------------------------      
}
```

Comment: post some code.

Comment: to get started write a program that displays one random number between 1 and 35. Then a second one that remebers the first number and genreates another one that is different from the first. Build up form there

Comment: "I'm using rand / srand to make "random" numbers." That's doing it the hard way. Research `std::vector`, `std::iota`, and `std::shuffle`. `std::sort` may also help.

Comment: Yea, I got the first part. I just dont know how to "evolve" the code from there. I've tried shuffle, but if somehow messed it up (havent learning shuffle etc yet). The rand is something our teachers at school said we should use. (Posted some code now)

Answer (score 0):

this code is meant to be instructive and help with your learning, it is not optimal as stated by other comments:

```
void randNr(int tal[]) {
    int count = 0;
    while (count < SIZE) {
        int number = rand() % 35 + 1;  // range [1, 35]

        int index = 0;
        // find where the number should be placed
        while (index < count && tal[index] < number) {
            index++;
        }

        // if it is not a duplicate, shift other numbers up, then add it
        if (tal[index] != number) {
            for (int i = count; i >= index; i--)
                tal[i + 1] = tal[i];
            tal[index] = number;
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```